# How to add custom playnow tab to the application page - Facebook

Tags: facebook, tabs

At this page : http://www.facebook.com/monsterfantasy

They have this button as you can see : [image]

**i want to have same features for my game application at facebook. how can i do that ? thank you.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Page tab in your [FB App settings](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#tabs). After that, you need to:

1. Add the Page Tab to your application *profile* page
2. go to your application *profile* page settings and set the default landing tab to your newly added tab.